# developing a data warehouse from parsed XML

Tags: xml, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

My purpose is to develop a data warehouse, for which i downloaded an XML file from [dblp (computer science bibliography website)](http://dblp.dagstuhl.de/xml/).
I then parsed that XML file using the [SAX](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) XML parser.

After parsing i now have the following entities (Closing tags aren't printed intentionally):

```
  <dblp>
    <www mdate key>
      <author>
      <title>
      <url>
      <year>
    <inproceedings mdate key>
      <author>
      <title>
      <month>
      <year>
      <pages>
      <booktitle>
      <url>
      <note>
      <cdrom>
    <article mdate key>
      <author>
      <author>
      <title>
      <journal>
      <volume>
      <month>
      <year>
    <book mdate key>
      <author>
      <title>
      <year>
      <publisher>
      <isbn>
      <url>
    <incollection mdate key publtype>
      <author>
      <author>
      <author>
      <title>
      <year>
      <booktitle>
      <ee>
      <crossref>
      <url>
    <proceedings mdate key>
      <editor>
      <editor>
      <editor>
      <title>
      <booktitle>
      <volume>
      <series href>
      <year>
      <isbn>
      <publisher>
      <url>
```

According to mu knowledge the next step now is to develop a dimensional model (star schema) out of these entities, but i don't understand how exactly i have to do this with this much data. (Note: Its my first data warehouse project)

Is this data enough? 
What are the things i have to take care of?

What should i do next?

Comment: There is LOADS of info on the net about this, look up Kimball for starters. After a bit of reading you'll realise that, when designing your star schema, it's not about the _data_, its about the _process_ that you're trying to model. It's also important (although not necessary) to have some kind of additive fact. The only one I see in your XML is count of book editions and/or articles.

Comment: Aside from what Nick has said, this question is really broad and also unclear. I don't understand why you're developing from an XML schema, I don't think there's any real answer to whether that's enough data, and it's not clear what you mean by "things [you] have to take care of." Potentially quite a lot! It sounds like - as Nick has suggested - you really need to learn the basics of dimensional modelling before you get going with this. SO isn't the right site for tutorial-style help of that kind, so you're best off looking elsewhere first, and coming back when you have specific questions.